# Security camera system server

Tags: server, software-recommendation, security, system

I'd like to setup a Security Camera system which is captures and stores video streams into Ubuntu Server From 2 wireless Cameras.

- Which type of motion-detecting wireless camera you suggested?
- Are there any software to capture the videos on schedule time from the server?
- And which software do i need to remote control the cameras?

Comment: I can't give you a full answer since I don't know answers to all of your questions, but as far as the software you could take a look at zoneminder: 
http://www.zoneminder.com/

Comment: If you have wireless cameras why would you need a video capture card?

Comment: @sergio91pt i don't have wireless camera yet ;)

Comment: You can do motion detection in software and use cheap cameras: http://linux.die.net/man/1/motion

Comment: Theres a compatibility list for zoneminder [here](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Compatibility_List), if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the majority of the IP cameras, as those shown in [this virtual shop](http://www.e-tronic-shop.com/mystore/esp/catalogo.php?kw=camara%20ip&Submit=Buscar), starting from $ 945.00 Mexican Pesos (almost 100 US Dollars), and this [D-Link DC-900](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=270) (the majority of them tested by me) resolves the motion detection, scheduled recording and remote control by itself (there are just a few which features 360° movement, remote controlled).

What I mean: All that you need is a good FTP Server where to drop the images/videos, which can also be Linux Based.

How to reach your cameras from outside is as easy as getting a Dynamic Domain Name Service and to use it in your modem/router or, if you have fixed IP then you don't have a problem, you will also be in need to route the specific ports to the cameras and make the cameras respond to the petitions of a specific port.

Everything can be monitored/controlled via web browser, like in this example of my security system which is embedding 3 cameras (1 of them remote controlled) in a single web page. (blurred where needed for privacy).

[image]

The remote controlled camera is the one [shown here](http://www.e-tronic-shop.com/mystore/esp/detalle.php?idc=0&id=43), with two-way audio (yes, you can speak to people close to the camera), wireless and infra-red night vision. (Sorry, I don't sell these cameras but I purchased over there in Mexico City.)

So, I would suggest you to look for a specific camera that fits your needs and if your intentions are to keep a backup of your videos in a server, look for FTP server guides here or even in the net.

Good luck!

## Edit:

Original DCS-900 Camera's Web Based Application

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is a great recommendation. but i'm not sure i know which application you using for monitoring. Is that the D-Link Camera's application?

Comment: The D-Link DCS-900 Camera is in the top right corner. That's a web based application which is embedding Java applets. They ship their own web based application as per the image in the Edit of my answer, of which you can easily extract the portions of code in order to make your own security system as I did in the four-square picture. If you need further assistance with encoding your own web application or wish a live preview, please keep me posted in order to run a test for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! that is a wonderful explanation. and i will let you know if i need help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/), which seems to be exactly what you are looking for in software. As for the hardware, there is a [list of cameras that work with ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Compatibility_List) that you can choose some hardware from. Choose something that has the features you require (network camera, certain resolution, low light, etc) from that list and it should work with ZoneMinder.

Answer (score 3):

ZoneMinder seems to be a complex piece of software ... I got it working for a simpler USB camera scenario -- maybe something in this helps...

1. Install packages and set up apache as described at: http://www.unixmen.com/use-your-cam-as-a-security-video-camera-with-zoneminder/ (follow instructions until they start adding the camera as a "monitor")
2. Set up your camera as described in http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Documentation#Check_that_your_Camera_Works.21
3. Read configuration notes for your camera; for me, that was http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Logitech_Webcam_Pro_9000 . In particular, you'll probably want to run `zmu -d /dev/video0 --verbose -V1 --query` (or with `-V2`) to list the supported modes of your camera. Sometimes, the Linux driver doesn't support as many modes as the Windows driver.
4. Set a higher shared memory limit [ [link](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_does_a_.27Can.27t_shmget%3a_Invalid_argument.27_error_in_my_logs_mean.3F_and_my_cameras_won.27t_display_video_at_higher_resolutions.) ]. For Ubuntu, you want to run `echo kernel.shmmax = 536870912 > /etc/sysctl.d/60-kernel-shm.conf`, then `sysctl -p` to set the maximum shared memory size to 512MB.
5. Restart zoneminder (`service zoneminder restart`).
6. `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and watch for errors; google them and reconfigure your camera until it works :)

Best of luck.