# How to manage security cameras in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, security, camera

I am setting up a server and chose ubuntu for the OS. The system will have 3 purposes, storing my wife's photography work, storing music for quick access to our entertainment system (will be running the system through the TV and through our surround sound) and will also serve as a DVR unit for a home security system I am going to put together.

What sort of software options are there for the Ubuntu system as far as a DVR with frame by frame playback. It does not need to be fancy but of course a variety of options are a nice touch.

Comment: Personally, I just I got 2 IP cameras with FTP functionality. Then I set up me pc as an FTP server, and the pics and videos download right to the server from the cameras

Comment: These questions might help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/75133/ubuntu-dvr-what-are-the-options?rq=1

http://askubuntu.com/questions/52764/security-camera-system-server?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Check out Zoneminder. It's a full featured security camera suite. Sorry this answer is  so short, but I'm on my phone.